# Drawing Steiner's Roman Surface in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw Steiner's Roman Surface in OpenGL, and I'm having some trouble getting the right normals so that the surface lights up correctly. I used the parametric equation from Wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_surface. For the normals, I did a partial differentiation with respect to theta, then phi, then crossed the partial differentials to get the normal.

This doesn't allow the surface to light up properly because the Roman Surface is a non-orientable surface. Hence, I was wondering if there's a way to get the right normals out so that the surface can light up correctly. I've tried negating the normals, for the whole surface, and part of the surface(negating for the 1st and last quarter of n), but it doesn't seem to work.

My current code is as follows:

```
double getRad(double deg, double n){
    return deg * M_PI / n;
}

int n = 24;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 2*n; j++){

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

                double x = -pow(r,4) * cos(2*getRad(i+0.5,n)) * pow(cos(getRad(j+0.5,n)),2) * cos(2*getRad(j+0.5,n)) * sin(getRad(i+0.5,n)) - 2 * pow(r,4) * pow(cos(getRad(i+0.5,n)),2) * pow(cos(getRad(j+0.5,n)),2) * sin(getRad(i+0.5,n)) * pow(sin(getRad(j+0.5,n)),2);
                double y = pow(r,4) * cos(getRad(i+0.5,n)) * cos(2*getRad(i+0.5,n)) * pow(cos(getRad(j+0.5,n)),2) * cos(2*getRad(j+0.5,n)) - 2 * pow(r,4) * cos(getRad(i+0.5,n)) * pow(cos(getRad(j+0.5,n)),2) * pow(sin(getRad(i+0.5,n)),2) * pow(sin(getRad(j+0.5,n)),2);
                double z = -pow(r,4) * pow(cos(getRad(i+0.5,n)),2) * cos(getRad(j+0.5,n)) * cos(2*getRad(j+0.5,n)) * sin(getRad(j+0.5,n)) - pow(r,4) * cos(getRad(j+0.5,n)) * cos(2*getRad(j+0.5,n)) * pow(sin(getRad(i+0.5,n)),2) * sin(getRad(j+0.5,n));



                glNormal3d(x, y, z);                
                glVertex3d(r*r*cos(getRad(i,n))*cos(getRad(j,n))*sin(getRad(j,n)),r*r*sin(getRad(i,n))*cos(getRad(j,n))*sin(getRad(j,n)),r*r*cos(getRad(i,n))*sin(getRad(i,n))*cos(getRad(j,n))*cos(getRad(j,n)));
                glVertex3d(r*r*cos(getRad(i+1,n))*cos(getRad(j,n))*sin(getRad(j,n)),r*r*sin(getRad(i+1,n))*cos(getRad(j,n))*sin(getRad(j,n)),r*r*cos(getRad(i+1,n))*sin(getRad(i+1,n))*cos(getRad(j,n))*cos(getRad(j,n)));
                glVertex3d(r*r*cos(getRad(i+1,n))*cos(getRad(j+1,n))*sin(getRad(j+1,n)),r*r*sin(getRad(i+1,n))*cos(getRad(j+1,n))*sin(getRad(j+1,n)),r*r*cos(getRad(i+1,n))*sin(getRad(i+1,n))*cos(getRad(j+1,n))*cos(getRad(j+1,n)));
                glVertex3d(r*r*cos(getRad(i,n))*cos(getRad(j+1,n))*sin(getRad(j+1,n)),r*r*sin(getRad(i,n))*cos(getRad(j+1,n))*sin(getRad(j+1,n)),r*r*cos(getRad(i,n))*sin(getRad(i,n))*cos(getRad(j+1,n))*cos(getRad(j+1,n)));
            glEnd();

            glFlush();

    }
}
```

Comment: You could calculate the normal for the plane of the quad you're drawing and use that (if it isn't planar draw two triangles instead), but I'd be interested to know if anyone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you're dealing with nonorientable surfaces (like Steiner's Romans, or the famous Möbius strip) you have to possiblilities: Enable double sided lighting

```
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
```

or you enable face culling and render the surface with two passes (front facing and back facing) – you'll have to negate the normals for the backface pass.

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK); // backside faces are NOT rendered
draw_with_positive_normals();
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
draw_with_negative_normals();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the double-sided lighting worked. Now I just have to figure out how to colour the back side. =)

Comment: @tempestfire2002: For that you should really use the second method. Makes things a lot easier in the long term.

Comment: @tempestfire2002 You can also use two-sided materials (using `GL_FRONT` and `GL_BACK` instead of `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` in the `glMaterial` calls) to give both sides different colors.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Two side materials get annoying, as soon as you want to use shaders.

Answer (score 0):

For every triangle you generate create one with the same coordinates/normals but wound/flipped the other way.

Comment: Technically I'm generating quads, though I did try that. It seems as though OpenGL replaces the normal instead of adding another one.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably get better results by splitting the polygon into two triangles - each would then be guaranteed to be planar. Further, you could can generate the normals from each triangle, or smooth them between neighboring triangles.

The other trick is to pre-generate your points into an array and then referencing the array in the glVertex call. That way you have more options about how to generate normals.

Also, you can render the normals themselves with a glBegin(GL_LINES) ... glEnd() sequence.

Comment: Just to elaborate on the (excellent) debugging tip of drawing the normals with lines: You usually want to draw a line from `M` to `M + N * scale` where `M` is the geometric center of the triangle (or where ever you calculated the normal from), `N` the surface normal and `scale` an appropriate factor that allow you to see what's going  on.